# How build system for store office files in access using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-office

hi
i want to built application for managing office document in database.
My decision using VB.NET and access database.Please guide me how to do?
Using available tool Visual Studio 2010(VB.NET) and Access 2007.

1)what  suitable table for access to store office document?Included time,id,office files and what again?
2)how use vb.net 2010 for insert,update,delete in access?

Comment: You should probably check with amazon for a VB.Net book. Your question is far too broad and basically asks *"How do I write an Access based business application in VB.Net?"* There is much to consider when using Access. You might be much better off going to MySql.

Comment: It may not be necessary to go to MySQL, it depends on whether the files are to be stored externally with path in the database, or as longblobs in the database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154707/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-media-files-on-a-database However, what will not be involved is Access, just Jet or ACE, the default database for Access.

Answer (score -1):

I'd start with using SQL Server as the back end and using Access Data Projects for the front end.

SQL Server 2008 supports FILESTREAM storage of varbinary(max) datatype.. and this could cut your storage overhead considerably.

Comment: The original question specifically stated VB.Net