# how to store an audio file with meta data in mysql database easily?

Tags: php, mysql, audio

I am doing a project of olnine music straming website.I have to store large amount of audio file with metadata(like: artist name,full duration,path of audio file,image for that audio file etc.).
    How can i store those audio  file in mysql database and retrive them for streming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to store media files on a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154707/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-media-files-on-a-database)

Comment: You can store the audio data in a blob column. A better idea though is to store the audio as a file and just store the filename in the db along with the meta data about the track. It is much easier to stream from files than from db blob columns.