# how to store voice and recognize from database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, voice-recognition, voice

i want to create web app with node js and react js.

there will be 2 page in in that web app one will be which record the voice and store in database and in second page any user can come and say anything after that web app will match that voice and with database and it will return with user name.

i already done record part saved in folder but don't know which database i should use to store data which can match data during second page when user need there name when they speak anything..

thanks in advance i new in node and react please help with this :D

Comment: For saving in the database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154707/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-media-files-on-a-database

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://firebase.google.com/ google's firebase as your real-time database or for storing audio files

- but for matching two voice it won't work for that you have to use some library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav-file-info

which will compare the voice input with audio which is in database

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to solve is part of automatic speech recognition (ASR). It is obvious you cannot compare two audio files in this problem domain. Rather, you need to compute some sort of feature/fingerprint of a voice and match those features. One of the common feature extraction algorithm is Mel-Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (MFCC)([click here](http://recognize-speech.com/feature-extraction/mfcc)). For python, I know a library named [python_speech_features](http://python-speech-features.readthedocs.io/). This library can extract MFCC features. For the purpose of matching features you can use a Machine Learning algorithm.